dispatch and connect in redux not working
I am a beginner to redux. I am trying to follow this tutorial to learn but it is a little outdated. I am having trouble with getting the code to work. I am building a social app following tutorial using react expo.
In the following code, there are a few issues:

fetchUser and fetchUserPosts are never called (the console log statements inside them never print)



import { USER_STATE_CHANGE, USER_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE } from '../constants/index.js'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import { auth, db } from '../../firebaseConfig.js'
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";


export function fetchUser() {
    console.log("fetchUser");
    return async (dispatch) => {
        const docRef = doc(db, "users", auth.currentUser.uid);
        const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef)
            // .then((docSnap) => {
            //     if (docSnap.exists) {
            //         console.log("fetch user dispatch");
            //         dispatch({ type: USER_STATE_CHANGE, currentUser: docSnap.data() })
            //     } else {
            //         console.log('does not exist')
            //     }
            // }).catch((error) => {
            //     console.log("Error getting document:", error);
            // });
        if (docSnap.exists) {
            console.log("fetch user dispatch");
            dispatch({ type: USER_STATE_CHANGE, currentUser: docSnap.data() })
        } else {
            console.log('does not exist')
        }
    }
}

export function fetchUserPosts() {
    console.log("fetchUserPosts");
    return ((dispatch) => {
        console.log("fetchUserPosts inside return");
        firebase.firestore()
            .collection("posts")
            .doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
            .collection("userPosts")
            .orderBy("creation", "asc")
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
                let posts = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                    const data = doc.data();
                    const id = doc.id;
                    return { id, ...data }
                })
                console.log("posts" + posts)
                dispatch({ type: USER_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE, posts })
            })
    })
}




when i uncomment the mapstatetoprops in my profile.js, it throws the error: no store property exists. my console log (console.log({ currentUser, posts });) also gives undefined. as a comment, the code runs and rest of the app runs but again the console log mentioned gives undefined.



import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, Image, FlatList } from 'react-native'
import { auth } from '../../firebaseConfig'

import { fetchUserPosts } from '../../redux/actions/index.js'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'

function Profile(props) {
  const { currentUser, posts } = props;
  console.log({ currentUser, posts });
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Profile</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  // currentUser: store.userState.currentUser,
  // posts: store.userState.posts,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Profile);



Here is my main js relavent code:


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ currentUser: state.user, });

const mapDispatchProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({ fetchUser, fetchUserPosts }, dispatch);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchProps)(main);



and here is the user js.


import { USER_STATE_CHANGE, USER_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE } from '../constants/index'

const initialState = {
    currentUser: null,
    posts: []
}

export const user = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case USER_STATE_CHANGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                user: action.currentUser
            }
        case USER_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: action.posts
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}



my constants:


export const USER_STATE_CHANGE = 'USER_STATE_CHANGE'
export const USER_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE = 'USER_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE'



Sorry for the long post. I have spent hours on it and I have no idea where I could make changes. i have tried everything in my knowledge. please let me kwow if anything else is needed.
Edit: configure store call:


const reducer = combineReducers({
  rootReducer
})
const store = configureStore({ reducer });


import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import LandingScreen from './components/auth/Landing';
import RegisterScreen from './components/auth/Register';
import MainScreen from './components/Main'
import LoginScreen from './components/auth/Login';
import AddScreen from './components/main/Add'
import SaveScreen from './components/main/Save'


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loaded: false,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        this.setState({
          loggedIn: false,
          loaded: true,
        })
      } else {
        this.setState({
          loggedIn: true,
          loaded: true,
        })
      }
    })
  }
  render() {
    const { loggedIn, loaded } = this.state;
    if (!loaded) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Loading</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }

    if (!loggedIn) {
      return (





import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import rootReducer from './redux/reducers'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'


const reducer = combineReducers({
  rootReducer
})
const store = configureStore({ reducer });


import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import LandingScreen from './components/auth/Landing';
import RegisterScreen from './components/auth/Register';
import MainScreen from './components/Main'
import LoginScreen from './components/auth/Login';
import AddScreen from './components/main/Add'
import SaveScreen from './components/main/Save'


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loaded: false,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        this.setState({
          loggedIn: false,
          loaded: true,
        })
      } else {
        this.setState({
          loggedIn: true,
          loaded: true,
        })
      }
    })
  }
  render() {
    const { loggedIn, loaded } = this.state;
    if (!loaded) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Loading</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }

    if (!loggedIn) {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Landing">
            <Stack.Screen name="Landing" component={LandingScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>

        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Landing">
            <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Add" component={AddScreen} navigation={this.props.navigation} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Save" component={SaveScreen} navigation={this.props.navigation} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>

      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default App




Did you mean to write state, not store here?
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  // currentUser: store.userState.currentUser,
  // posts: store.userState.posts,
})

That said, please don't use connect and mapStateToProps - those are legacy apis for about 5 years now and won't get any more updates.
Use the useSelector hook instead.

Ok thanks. I am reading docs to figure out how to convert. If you can give an example that would be nice too. Also sorry, i mean store in that code instead of state. but i now get the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentUser' of undefined

But, in your own code, you define a state variable that references the current contents of your store. I am very certain that you would have to use state.userState.currentUser, not store.userState.currentUser. There is no store variable, and you'd never reference the contents of the store by directly referencing the store.

As for userState not being present in your state, you probably set up your reducers up wrong. Could you show your configureStore (or, deprecated createStore) call?

Generally, you are writing a 5 years outdated style of Redux here - I'm sorry to tell you this, but modern Redux doesn't look like this at all - you are probably following extremely outdated tutorials. It would probably be a good idea if you restarted with the official tutorial: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts
Modern Redux is about 1/3 the code of legacy Redux and much more safe against errors.

Thank you for the replies! I have added the configure store code at the end. this is where I define the store. Also, I keep getting this error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentUser' of undefined even though currentUser seems to be working in other parts of my app. That's unfortunate. Would it be too much work to convert the code to modern redux? I am assuming I will learn faster this way cause I can understand the changes I am making.

Right now, you have your store set up in a way that you have state.rootReducer.userState.currentUser. To fix that up, you'd just do configureStore({ reducer: rootReducer }); and skip the combineReducers. I'd recommend you to go through the tutorial first and decide afterwards if you want to migrate any code over. I don't assume that you have a lot of code yet, since with the setup you currently have it doesn't seem like it could ever have worked so far. Writing it from zero might actually be less work than trying to convert it.

I also assume that your rootReducer is another call to combineReducers in another file, and in modern Redux you don't need combineReducers at all. You also don't need hand-written action creators, ACTION_TYPES, hand-written immutable reducer update logic, mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps etc. etc.
Also, just to add this: in React, nowadays you'd also not use any class components. Whatever sources you are using to learn React are pre-2019. I'm really sorry to tell you this, but most of the concepts you've learned there are not future proof. Learn React from https://react.dev/ .

Thanks! I will go through the tutorial. Before you go, can you also help me fix the bug with statechange: upon starting the app, the switch always goes to default case (I put a console log in there and it prints multiple times.). why is the switch never going through the user_state_change? I am also getting currentUser as null which is what is is initialized as which I assume is related. but I am able to log in through auth and my user stays logged in and the components are working. Thanks again.

yes, this is my index file in reducers: import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { user } from "./user";
const Reducers = combineReducers({
userState: user,

});

export default Reducers

Do configureStore({ reducer: {  userState: user} }); instead. As for the switch: the default case will be hit in any unrelated action, e.g. the initial action of your store. But don't care about it too much. Modern Redux doesn't have switch cases ;)

nvm. typo with componentDidMount. though now i'm getting: Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'undefined'. You may need to add middleware to your store setup to handle dispatching other values. i should be able to figure it out. thanks though!
